# Study of $\mathbb Q(\xi_{12})/\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Today I am studying the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{12})/\mathbb Q$, more precisely I want to study its subfield and associated subgroups in the Galois group.
 I already know that 
  $
  G=\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{12}):\mathbb Q ) \cong (\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z)^\times \cong \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z  $
and so the nonzero proper subgroups of the Galois group $G$ are the three proper subgroups of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.

How do I write explicitly the corresponding subfields in $\mathbb Q(\xi_{12})$ of these subgroups? Is there a fixed technique to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a correspondence between subgroups and intermediate fields. In particular, the index of the subgroup is equal to the extension degree of the intermediate field. Normally you can find some elements that are certainly in the corresponding intermediate field (just check that it is fixed by all elements in the subgroup). A dimension argument usually is sufficient to conclude that you have found the intermediate field.

Comment: I’ve given some guidance to your specific question in my answer below. But for general extensions, where the Galois group may be much more complicated, describing the intermediate fields may be rather tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Among the twelfth roots of unity are the cube roots of unity and the fourth roots of unity. A $\xi_3$ is $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{-3\,}}2$, and $i$ is a fourth root. I think you can spot the other quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3},i)$.